# Identity for generalized hypergeometric function

Tags: derivatives, hypergeometric-function

> I want to show
> $$
> (z \frac{d}{dz} + a_j){}_p F_q(a_1,...,a_j,...a_p;b_1,...,b_q;z) = a_j {}_p F_q(a_1,...,a_j+1,...a_p;b_1,...,b_q;z),
> $$
> as is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Differentiation).

My problem is, that I'm stuck at this step:
$$(z \frac{d}{dz} + a_j){}_p F_q(a_1,...,a_p;b_1,...,b_q;z) =\\
 z \frac{a_1...a_p}{b_1...b_q}F_q(a_1+1,...,a_p+1;b_1+1,...,b_q+1;z) + a_j{}_p F_q(a_1,...,a_p;b_1,...,b_q;z)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity we will show this for $a_1$ and denote $\mathbf a=\{a_2,\dots,a_p\}$, $(\mathbf a)_k=\prod_{l=2}^p(a_l)_k$, $\mathbf b=\{a_1,\dots,a_q\}$, and $(\mathbf b)_k=\prod_{l=1}^q(b_l)_k$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
(z \tfrac{d}{dz} + a_1){_pF_q}(a_1,\mathbf a;\mathbf b;z)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1)_k(\mathbf a)_k}{(\mathbf b)_k\,k!}(z \tfrac{d}{dz}z^k + a_1z^k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1)_k(\mathbf a)_k}{(\mathbf b)_k\,k!}(zkz^{k-1}+ a_1z^k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1)_k(\mathbf a)_k}{(\mathbf b)_k\,k!}(k+ a_1)z^k.
\end{align} 
$$
But
$$
(k+ a_1)(a_1)_k
=a_1\frac{(a_1+k)\Gamma(a_1+k)}{a_1\Gamma(a_1)}
=a_1\frac{\Gamma(a_1+1+k)}{\Gamma(a_1+1)}
=a_1(a_1+1)_k,
$$
and so
$$
(z \tfrac{d}{dz} + a_1){_pF_q}(a_1,\mathbf a;\mathbf b;z)
=a_1\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1+1)_k(\mathbf a)_k}{(\mathbf b)_k\,k!}z^k=a_1{_pF_q}(a_1+1,\mathbf a;\mathbf b;z),
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: thank you so much! It really helped me.